# What is the probability that the $i$th draw is black?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose an urn contains sever chips labeled $1,\dots,7.$ Three of the chips are black, two are red, and two are green. The chips are drawn randomly one at a time without replacement until the urn is empty.

My confusion is that a black ball could have been drawn on one of the $i-1$th cases so my guess is that I'm supposed to do it by cases. Any suggestions?

I know the denominator is $\#\Omega=7\cdot 6\dots (i-1)$.

I defined $X_i$ as the number of draws I need to get a black chip but I don't think that's what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Are you trying to compute the probability that the $i$-th draw is black, or the expected number of draws to get the first black chip?

Comment: I believe ith draw is black. It turns out that A=3x6!, Omega=7!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pay attention to the colors of the other balls, the chance the $i^{th}$ draw is black is the same as the chance the first draw is black.  You can do a lot of work by cases to come out with this, or you can imagine drawing $i$ balls in order, then swapping the first and $i^{th}$ balls.